# How to display my current time in Linux (server shows date in GMT but my time should be GMT+8)?

Tags: linux, unix, date

when I use the 'date' command, our server gives the GMT time. But my current time should be GMT+8. How do I display my current time as GMT+8? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This would be better on Server Fault or Super User.  What distribution do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the a line like this to your `.profile` file, then log out and in again:

```
TZ='Australia/Perth'; export TZ
```

The available timezones are usually in `/usr/share/zoneinfo/`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [set your time zone](http://www.linuxsa.org.au/tips/time.html)

Comment: Thanks zengr for your reply. But I have no root permission. (the server is badly maintain by a remote site admin.) Is there a way that I create a simple script, say myDate, to do it? Thanks.

Comment: So, you want to display your local time (GMT+8) when you type "date" in your remote server's terminal? I assume you login by SSH.

Comment: You got the answer by @caf :)